# Tesseract + Leptonica OpenCV cmake undefined reference to `pixReadFromMultipageTiff'

Tags: cmake, ocr, tesseract

I am trying configure and start Tesseract OCR on my opencv c++ detection project. I want include tesseract into my c++ project and I think that I have (stupid) problem with linker. (I am not experienced guy in programming with Cmake and so on...)

I installed tesseract and leptonica. Trying to compile my project.

- -lp (<- directory with project)
- --lp.cpp (<-main code)
- --CmakeLists.txt
- --cascade.xml (Opencv trained classifier)

My CmakeLists.txt looks like: http://pastebin.com/pBW7Kz3Z

When I use *$ cmake .* , it creates makefile and after *$ make* I see this error (I cannot make it): http://pastebin.com/MYchSYCm

Please help with this :(. I know it will be kinda stupid mistake, but I'll really appreciate solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing Leptonica 1.74 [`allheaders.h`](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/blob/master/src/allheaders.h) file.